# Inkscape - How do I remove the black background in a jpg file of scanned dice?

Tags: inkscape, transparency, background-removal

[image][image]I have scanned a bunch of dice on a flatbed scanner. I covered the dice so the background would get as black as I could. (which means it is not uniformly completely black black)

Now I have loaded that jpg file into Paint and cut out the part that I want and pasted it into Inkscape 0.92.

I wish to get rid of that background as I want to place the dice over an open locker and the original black background is too black.

How do I do that?

Best Regards
Peter
Denmark

Comment: Uhhh, you should probably be using Gimp for this.

Comment: Ok. and cut it out with the scissors or how ?

Comment: You actually cannot get clean cuts just in this case. I added something about it to my answer.

Comment: I'd use a white background, for contrast with the black dice, and would then use gimp to change white to transparent.

Answer (score 2):

You have possibly painted yourself into a corner. In theory, you could use a photo editor and with clipping paths or polygonal lasso tool manually select those areas which contain the background, then delete them (i.e. replace with transparency). But you must know or guess which is the background: no automatic method can do it. Then you would save as PNG or other format which supports transparency.

Scanners have very short distance range of sharp imaging. The far ends of the dice are unsharp and totally mixed with the black background. A high quality photo would be an easier case.

You must have some background. But the shading of the dice will visually match only to a black one, so removing it is useless. If you had something white or colored in the gaps between the dice, the appearance would be totally impossible. That's what I meant when I wrote, "you have painted yourself into a corner."

Here is one piece cut out in GIMP to show what you can get at best. If you manage to delete the gap areas between the pieces, all pieces fade to black at the edges. They look dirty against any background other than black:

[image]

Of course, you might like that appearance, so try it. I have removed hundreds of backgrounds from photos which are printed in ads, books and magazines. Now and then I have met the same problem: the lights and shadows in the image only match the removed background.

**What to do:** Scan again - or rather take a photo, but with grey background. You cannot fix full black nor full white, but neutral grey has room in all directions. The unsharpness of the far ends in the scanned image makes clean cuts impossible, but a camera can make a sharp image.

If you have a flat surface LED lamp, place your dice on it. Put a white paper between the dice and the lamp to keep the background light intensity low enough.

There's also the tiling option. Your dice are all seen from the same direction. You can tile them, you actually need only few original images, where the background has been removed. The numbers can be synthetic (=written in a graphics program).

I made an attempt of tiling. I haven't any good dice photos, so it's only a drawing. Real photos would be a light year more plausible:

[image]

BTW. If you like to wrestle a little in Inkscape, draw one die:

[image]

Comment: Grey could work, or *better yet* a colour on the ***opposite*** *side* of the colour wheel from your primary defined colour - red (its inverse or complement) which is a green at RGB 34,189,80; close to web hex of #86BD50; roughly equivalent to CMYK at 75%, 0%, 95%, 0%. Or given easily availability, a standard green-screen colour would work perfectly I'm sure.

Comment: Now I have managed to use Gimp to mark out the dice a bit close and cut out the rest. If I pasted the dice into Inkscape it's still a rectangle but now black is really black around the dice. How do I turn that black into transparant?

Comment: Hmmm. I think I can make do by converting the marked object to path and then insert several extra points on line parts and then move those points.

Comment: @PeterLageri  Copying and pasting between applications in Windows often causes loss of transparency.  Instead try exporting the image from GIMP as a PNG file. Then import the PNG into Inskcape.

Comment: Thank you all for your input. It is all very much appreciated. I have added a picture of a result I'm ok with. The image is used for a tuckbox for a boardgame called Dark Moon. Again thank you all!